# E: Unable to locate package php5-intl Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, apache2, php

I try to update composer but got this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package bower-asset/admin-lte could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package bower-asset/font-awesome could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 4
    - The requested package bower-asset/html5shiv could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 5
    - The requested package bower-asset/jquery-slimscroll could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 6
    - The requested package bower-asset/flot could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

So I tried to install the php5-intl extension using: `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`. But sadly I got this error...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-intl
```

So, what do I need to do to fix this problem? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 comes with php7.  So unless you've gone out of the way to install php5, you're trying to add a module in the wrong version.

Try...

```
apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

Comment: for PHP 7+, use **sudo apt-get install php-intl**

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, and PHP5.6 below command works fine.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-intl
```